# Does Google not support rich snippets for reviews of the schema.org type VideoGame?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

When you search for "site:videochums.com/review", some reviews no longer have rich snippets. I recently changed the reviews to include the type "VideoGame" as opposed to what I had before; "SoftwareApplication". Are the rich snippets not showing because Google doesn't support VideoGame? I tried the Structured Data Testing Tool and everything validates perfectly, so I'm thoroughly confused.

Here's an example of a review page in case you'd like to examine the markup: [URL removed]

Any help will greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not display a Review Rich Snippet for all of the Schema.org types, but they don’t explicitly list which types are [supported](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews) (emphasis mine):

> We support reviews and ratings **for a wide range of schema.org types**, including businesses, products, and different creative works such as books or movies.

*Maybe* it is relatated to the fact that `VideoGame` is a relatively new type, [added](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html) 2014-12-11.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helps me understand a bit more. It's very annoying how Google is so secretive about everything.

Answer (score 0):

At least now in 2022 google says:

> Google also supports reviews for the following schema.org types (and their subtypes):
> ...
> Game
> ...

As [VideoGame](https://schema.org/VideoGame) is a (direct) subtype of [Game](https://schema.org/Game) so it should work.

Otherwise, if it doesn't work (especially in other cases where the type is not one of the listed ones and also not a direct subtype the following may work. Its an example for cars from [Google updates product structured data for car review snippets](https://searchengineland.com/google-updates-product-structured-data-for-car-review-snippets-378924)

where it says:

> Car schema is not supported automatically as a subtype of product schema.

and suggest to use:

```
"@type": ["Product", "Car"],
```

The same for VideoGame may look like:

```
"@type": ["Game", "VideoGame"],
```